# Long AMPL model preparation time

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization, linear-programming

We deal with a large-scale linear optimization problem (~50000 variables and ~4000000 constraints). We use **AMPL Studio** modeling environment for problem modeling and then calling linear solver (**CPLEX, Gurobi**, etc.). However, before calling a solver, the preparation process (generation of LP or MPS file I guess?) of such model takes ~950 seconds.

Profiling shows that most of the time is consumed by **AMPL**'s `genmod` function. Is it normal that preparation of such model (for the solver) takes so long?

If so, could you suggest an alternative way to generate model faster? As far as I am aware, **AMPL** is among the leader's for such job compared to other **AMLs**.

Comment: I cannot speak to AMPL, but I had similar issues modeling in Python and found that [JuMP](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/JuMP.jl) worked _much_ faster. It can also serve as a frontend to CPLEX and Gurobi. If you try this, I'd be interested to hear how it turns out.